# Wordnet returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordnet

I'm using the `words` gem to search wordnet. Here is my code:

```
require 'words'
data = Words::Wordnet.new
word = "geese"
lemma = data.find(word)
puts lemma
```

`lemma` returns `nil`. It works for other words like "car" but "geese" doesn't work. The word exists, I can search for it on the Wordnet website: http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=geese&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=&o8=1&o1=&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=00000000000

What could be going on? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because "geese" is a plural (an irregular one at that), and the search on the WordNet website is using [morphy](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/morphy.7WN.html). I guess the words gem isn't. Try "cars" and "feet".

Comment: I think the "words" gem is using the same dictionary as wordnet. Are you sure it's different?

Comment: They are using the same dictionary, but the dictionary only has the uninflected word forms. I believe the WordNet website is doing some inflectional morphology processing that the words gem isn't. So if you search for things like plurals and -ing forms you'll find the base forms on the WordNet website, but the words gem won't give you anything unless those forms also happen to be base forms of other words (this happens often with -ed verbs turned into adjectives).

Comment: Ah, ok, gotcha. That's not good... I guess I will use the wordnet gem. Thank you for your answer.